# hitTestObject not working properly within a for loop

Tags: flash-cc

I'm building a game where the hero is build with a MovieClip that has nested Movieclips. The nested MovieClips are the moves of the hero which are in different frames. Additionally, there are some MovieClips that are two levels nested.

Now here is the code of what I'm doing:

```
    public function movesCollisions(event:Event):void{

        for (var ea:int = 0; ea < enemies.length; ea++){
              //parent  .child     .sibling     
             if(sketch.slidepunch.sketchfist.hitTestObject(enemies[ea])){

                enemies[ea].animstate = "defeated";
            //Here this first collision works fine but the next 
            //collsion below does not, I have no Idea why.  

     }else if(sketch.archforward.rhandHit.hitTestObject(enemies[ea])){

                enemies[ea].animstate = "defeated";

             }

                }
            }
```

The problem that I'm having is that the hitTestObject does not work when I have the else if conditional. The first one works if I comment out the else statement. How can I fix this issue since I have many more moves that I need to check for collision.

They only way that I have manage to get the moves collision to work has been by creating a different Event.ENTER_FRAME, function for each but it has a big effect on performance.

any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? can you paste some error log?

Comment: What I mean by does not work is that the hittestobject no longer detects collision because of "else if" ...I did some trace on the object for the else if and surprisingly as soon as the game started, the hero started falling through its set y coordinate. Another interesting thing, as soon as I activate the second move(hitestobject) the hero shows up in the proper y coordinate. as soon as I release the key it starts falling. Flash is not giving me any error when I debug the project.